# Delete Hidden Rows In Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, rows, hidden

I have data in excel 2010 where data in one cell is hidden which is not visible but when I copy and paste special that part the data appears in that cell.

How to view and delete that hidden data/rows from excel 2010.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind a 2 step approach, you can do "Find and Select...", then "Go To Special..." and then pick "Visible Cells Only". This highlights only the visible cells, you can ctrl+C and paste it to another sheet. The shorthtcut for highlighting the visible cells is also:  "alt+;"

For the future you might want to move to Stackexchange forum for Excel related questions, as SOF is focused on coding.

Comment: Not Working.When I do paste special then hidden slot also get copied.

Comment: That would be the way to do it. Did you try to open a fresh sheet and try with some sample values? Perhaps the sheet you use so far had some other issues. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Locate-hidden-cells-on-a-worksheet-94d66405-2d11-486d-925b-3575da95e5d8

Comment: Hi Thx for replying.Exactly I want to remove cell value that is got hidden in merged cells.I don't know the exact cell location where the hidden data is.So how to select complete sheet and remove hidden data in merged cells.So that hidden data does not get copied.